# Compress a file while uploading to s3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, compression, boto3, bytesio

I'm writing "bytes" to a file on s3 remote, using `boto3.client`. Is there a way to write data while compressing it simultaneously?
eg. using some option like `codec="snappy"` or something like that?

Code:

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
bytesio = io.BytesIO()
bytesio.write(bytes_data)
bytesio.seek(0)
key = OUTPUT_REMOTE_DIR + test.avro
s3.put_object(Body=bytesio.getvalue(), Bucket=OUTPUT_BUCKET, Key=key)
```

Comment: Do you just mean something like `Body=gzip.compress(bytesio.getvalue())` ?

Comment: @AnonCoward I tried `snappy.compress(bytes_data)`, which compresses the actual data (for my use case, 2.8GB was down to 1.0GB). But then, when I'm reading the avro file back, I'm getting error and there is no way to specify `codec` in `fastavro.reader`